# C# Collection Initializer Syntax to an existing collection

Tags: c#

There's a syntax in C# that I discovered recently that enables you to initialize a read-only collection during initialization:

```
class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; } = new List<Bar>();
}

var foo = new Foo
{
    Bars = 
    {
        new Bar()
    }
}
```

Which is great as it leads to very expressive code. But I have a situation where I already have a collection of `Bar`, and I want to initialize it using this syntax (even though Bars is `readonly`). **Is there a way to do this?**

```
var bar = new List<Bar>();
var foo = new Foo
{
    Bars =  bar // error: Property or indexer Foo.Bar cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
}
```

Comment: If you could change `Foo`, you can simply add a constructor that takes `List<Bar>` as an argument - `var foo = new Foo(bar);`

Comment: Allow the `Foo` constructor to take `Bar` as a parameter and change to this `public List<Bar> Bars = { get; private set; }`

Comment: Either add a setter or a constructor. It's a difference whether you assign it inline in the class(which is allowed without setter) or from outside.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia `private set;` is useful in c#5, but in c#6 you can have read-only properties by only specifying `{get;}`.

Comment: @LeonardoSeccia `private set` will work from outside the `Foo` ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: of course not, it's `private` ;-) OP is trying to assign something from outside even if the property is readonly. Why should that work? That would be a bug.

Comment: @Rango It will if you use reflection :-)

Comment: @ZoharPeled if there is will there is a way  :D

Comment: @Rango that's what i thought but things nowadays changing so fast, needed to confirm :D

Comment: I must admit that i don't understand the question fully. Is there a real need to assign this collection from outside even if the property is readonly? Or could you simply use `{ get; set; }`? Then the question is redundant. Otherwise you had to use reflection, but i strongly recommend against. If you can't change the class you could still fill that list from outside: `foo.Bars.AddRange(bar)`. Then it isn't the same list instance but the same content.

Comment: Actually it smells to me that there is a logical error in that piece of code, don't you guys? I think readonly means you could not set it's value, and you should populate bar inside the foo not from outside. If you want to set it's value from outside why do you make it readonly? I am confuse a bit :)

Comment: seems like OP is experimenting with it

Comment: I guess OP either doesn't know that `var foo = new Foo{ Bars =  bar }` is trying to assign something to a property that has no setter(allowed only inline or from constructor). Or he doesn't know that he could simply add that setter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to initialize it using this syntax (even though Bars is readonly)

You simply cannot.

As we are using the initializer syntax and it actually call the setter method aka `set` of the property and you have a **readonly** property which can only be set by the class itself and for setting it form outside the class we need to pass it via constructor of `Foo` while creating it's instance.

### UPDATE:

The first example code actually ends up call to `Add` method of the `List<T>`. It will compiled to following code:

```
 Foo foo = new Foo();
 foo.Bars.Add(new Bar());
```

While you can add new items to the `Bars` but you cannot change it's reference to point to a different object directly using the initializer due to read-only property while it's totally legit to call the member method of `List<Bar>` on the instance like `Remove`, `Find` etc.

Comment: Actually, a get only property is not only readonly, it's immutable - you can only set it's value in the constructor of the type.

Comment: It's what I expected, but ... do you know how the other example (the one initializing it directly) works? My guess is that under the hood it's calling the .Add member of the collection.

Comment: @BrunoBrant can you provide that in a fiddle as working example ?

Comment: @BrunoBrant you are correct, it internally converts it to `Add` method call.

Comment: From C# 9.0 onwards, you can use `{ get; init; }` to enable assigning at initialization time, i.e. `new Foo { Bars = something }` will work, but `var foo = new Foo(); foo.Bars = something;` will not.